# SQL - Find Sales Orders that Contain Specific Item Combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have "Order" table that has OrderID and ItemID.

In "ItemCombo" table, I have "ItemID1" and "ItemID2".

How do I find Orders that have Items from both ItemID1 and ItemID2?

[image: Order table]

[image: ItemCombo table]

In this example, I want to return OrderID 10001 and 10003 - 10001 has item A & F while 10003 has item S and Y.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following query:

```
select o.OrderID
from ItemCombo i
inner join (select distinct OrderId from Orders) o
    on exists (
        select 1
        from Orders o1
        where o1.OrderId = o.OrderID and o1.ItemID = i.ItemID1
    )
    and exists (
        select 1
        from Orders o1
        where o1.OrderId = o.OrderID and o1.ItemID = i.ItemID2
    )
```

This works by joining distinct `OrderID`s from table `Orders` with `ItemCombo`, with correlated subqueries that ensure that values from both columns of `ItemCombo` are available for the given `OrderIdD`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ff972576d15c4232ffc029934bae17a)**:

```
| OrderId |
| ------: |
|   10001 |
|   10003 |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT o1.OrderID
FROM [ItemCombo] ic
  INNER JOIN [Order] o1 ON ic.ItemID1 = o1.ItemID
  INNER JOIN [Order] o2 ON ic.ItemID2 = o2.ItemID
WHERE o1.OrderID = o2.OrderID
GROUP BY o1.OrderID
ORDER BY o1.OrderID ASC
```

... or using the following:

```
SELECT o1.OrderID 
FROM [Order] o1 
  INNER JOIN [Order] o2 ON o1.OrderID = o2.OrderID AND o1.ItemID <> o2.ItemID
  INNER JOIN ItemCombo ic ON o1.ItemID = ic.ItemID1 AND o2.ItemID = ic.ItemID2
ORDER BY o1.OrderID ASC
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f2c36e770df3d46fbc2fa91f1689a97d)